# vscode ssh public key authentication fails with GitLab

Tags: git, ssh, visual-studio-code, gitlab

I'm hosting a private repository on GitLab and SourceTree and VSCode. I using the repository with SSH. Created a public and private key on C:.ssh (default location on Windows) and source tree seems to work fine with that - push and pulls are successfull.

For some reason, VSCode cannot push/pull (but can commit) as it's getting this error:

> Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

When running git pull from bash or command-line it also working good. The problem is only with VSCode.
I read some things online and saw I'm not the only one facing it, but couldn't find a solution.

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: Try starting `ssh-agent` from the same cmd before starting `code` like `D:\>"c:\Program Files\Git\cmd\start-ssh-agent.cmd"`

Comment: Can here looking for an answer about how to set up VSCode to use SSH to auth GitLab comms.  Did we get anywhere with that?